# $resource is undefined in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngresource, ngcordova

Wondering if anyone has come across this.. I have a project that makes use of Ionic, ngCordova, and ngResource. I import them in what I believe is the right order;

```
<!-- Angular Modules -->
<script src="lib/ng-biscuit/dist/ng-biscuit.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<!-- ngCordova -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

My factory is pretty simple;

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('test')
        .factory('TestService', TestService);

    TestService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function TestService($resource) {
        console.log('creating TestService ' + JSON.stringify($resource));
    }
})();
```

On a browser, I get an expected log of an object, but when I run this in an emulator, I get:

```
creating TestService undefined
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Can you show your 'test' module definition? It should be something like `angular.module('test', ['ngResource', 'ngCordova', ...])`

Comment: it's angular.module('test', ['ngResource'])

Comment: I think it's working, JSON.stringify just translates it to undefined since it's a function. You can just log $resource and it'll log the function or step in with dev tools and see the function.

Comment: @BradBarber Just pulled my hair out for hours on that one...man, can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    'use strict';

 app.factory('testService', [
  '$dependencyInjection',
  function($dependencyInjection) {
          
          var factory = {};
          
          ...
          
          return factory;
          }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

'use strict';

```
app.factory('testService', [
    '$dependencyInjection',
    function($dependencyInjection) {

      var factory = {};

      ...

      return factory;
      }]);
```

did this work for you ??